# Symfony2 Twig Change Sub-Loop Limit (Batch filter)

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, twig

First;
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html

My problem is, i want to show x images based on loop index.

if batch loop is odd then show 2 images (loop twice in sub-loop), else show only 1 image. (loop just once in sub-loop).

Here is my code but it's not working.

Any idea?

```
{% set batch_value = 2 %}
{% for row in getImages(gallery, 'Galeri', 'Detay')|slice(0, 5)|batch(batch_value) %}
    <div class="gallery-column {% if loop.index is odd %}gallery-thumbs{% else %}gallery-original{% endif %}">
        {% for image in row|slice(0, loop.index is odd ? 2 : 1) %}
            <div class="image-item">
                <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="{{ asset(image.image) }}">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="{{ asset(image.image) }}">
                    </figure>
                    <div class="text-wrapper">
                        <div class="align-content">
                            <div class="text-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-search"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                {{ batch_value }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if loop.index is odd %}
            {% set batch_value = 1 %}
        {% else %}
            {% set batch_value = 2 %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's not working as i want. Just printing 2 items for each row. I want to print 2, 1, 2 items in total 5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but I hope this helps:

Boilerplate code

```
{% set images = getImages(gallery, 'Galeri', 'Detay') %}
{% for key, row in images|slice(0, 5)|batch(big == false ? 2 : 1) %}
    {% for image in row %}
        <img src="{{ asset(images[key].image) }}" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't really see why you would need the inner loop when you already have the variable assigned to "row"